How to exclude temporary files from being packed into JAR by Maven?
If I run mvn package, while a file -- such as src/main/resources/log4j2.xml -- is open in gvim, Maven will copy the .log4j2.xml.swp into target/classes/ and then bundle it in the target JAR.
How would I exclude anything matching the .??* glob-pattern? The pom.xml is fairly simple (albeit with very large list of dependencies), and, in particular, the only <plugin> under <build> is:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>classpath-generation</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <platforms>
                                <platform>unix</platform>
                            </platforms>
                            <unixScriptTemplate>src/templates/tools_env.sh</unixScriptTemplate>
                            <assembleDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</assembleDirectory>
                            <binFolder>.</binFolder>
                            <generateRepository>false</generateRepository>
                            <programs>
                                <program>
                                    <id>tools_env.sh</id>
                                    <mainClass>-</mainClass>
                                </program>
                            </programs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


Seems you are running with default settings on the Jar Plugin, which will copy these temporary files.
Take control yourself and follow the documentation:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/index.html
To exclude content you could use something like
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.swp</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

